# String extraction in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am new in iphone  ,I stil confusing with strig extraction..

I hav an array named members array...Content shown below

Members array is(

```
{
aboutme = "I'm Amazing ";
avatar = "http://www.appsaddict.biz/uploads/thumb/2694_imge.png";
dob = "07-22-1978";
gender = 1;
height = 266;
looking = 2;
name = NYMan;
"user_id" = 112;
username = "Other-email@excite.com";
width = 200;
```

I Have a varible named "avatar" and its value is   "http://www.appsaddict.biz/uploads/thumb/1990imge.png"   I want to extract t  imagename ie 1990imge.png     from this varible .Anybody help me to extract this...advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *imgName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
```